# Implement these gestures on the gridview: Double tap; Long tap,drag and drop

Tags: flutter, gridview, gesture

Implement these gestures on the gridview:  Double tap; Long tap,drag and drop
To implement these gestures on the squares:

Double tap: Change the Colour of the tapped square (red,yellow,green,black)
Long tap: Open a PopUp with the possibility to select a colour and set the colour in case of selection
Drag&Drop: Drag the Colour of one square to another square and override the colour of the square where droped with the dragged colour.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Meine erste App'),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {});
            createAlertDialog(context).then((onValue) {});
          },
        ),
        body: GridView(
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2, mainAxisSpacing: 10, crossAxisSpacing: 10),
            children: [
              AnimatedContainer(
                color: Colors.red,
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              Container(color: Colors.green),
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ]));
  }
```

Comment: use GestureDetector

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Comment: i already tried but it only recreated another gridview